# Doubt on the differentiability of this function over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

The exercise asks me to show if $f(x) = x^2\vert x \vert $ is differentiabile over $\mathbb{R}$.

Here is my work.

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)^2\vert x+h\vert - x^2\vert x \vert}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x^2\vert x+h\vert + h^2\vert x+h\vert + 2xh \vert x+h\vert - x^2\vert x\vert}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x^2(\vert x+h\vert - \vert x \vert) + h\vert x+h\vert(h + 2x)}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x^2(\vert x+h\vert - \vert x \vert)(\vert x+h\vert + \vert x \vert)}{h(\vert x+h\vert + \vert x \vert )} + \lim_{h\to 0} \vert x+h\vert(h + 2x)$$

The second piece goes to $2x \vert x \vert$ hence it's ok.

About the first one:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x^2(\vert x+h\vert^2 - \vert x \vert ^2)}{h(\vert x+h\vert + \vert x \vert)} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x^2(h + 2x)}{\vert x+h\vert + \vert x \vert}$$

Here is where I got stuck, because I don't know how to proceed exactly between those two ways:

- I go on, finding $\lim_{h\to 0} x^2 \frac{2x}{\vert 2x \vert}$ hence the problem is at $x = 0$, even if there isn't actually a problem, hence it's differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$
- I calculate both the limits for $h\to 0^+$ and $h\to 0^-$, noticing the only problem occurs at $x = 0$, but again the $x$ simplify.

Seems like in both cases I get $x^2 \text{sgn}(x)$.

Which by the way completes the right derivative which is $2x\vert x \vert + x^2 \text{sgn}(x)$

Can you tell me if I'm wrong, where and how to remedy?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x)$ is clearly differentiable for all  $x \in (0,\infty) \cup (-\infty,0)$, to show that $f(x)$ is differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$ we need to prove that it is differentiable at $0$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2|x| -0}{x-0} =\lim_{x\to 0}x|x| =0$$
since the limit exist it is differentiable at $0$ hence it is differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$

if you want to continue with your approach
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x^2(|x+h|-|x|)}{h} =\lim_{h\to 0}(x^2) *  \ 
 \lim_{h\to 0}(\frac{(|x+h|-|x|)}{h})$$

note $\lim_{h\to 0}(\frac{(|x+h|-|x|)}{h}) =\frac{d}{dx}(|x|) =\operatorname{ sgn}(x)$

so the derivative is $x^2\operatorname{ sgn}(x) +x|x| $

Answer (score 1):

Since f is differentiable in $(0, +\infty), (-\infty , 0)$, we need to examine if it's differentiable at $x=0$.
As $lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h+0)-f(0)}{h}=0$, we have that f is differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$